# Como usar um Bundle com um tipo não primitivo?

Tags: android

Estou com a seguinte classe criada por mim:

```
public class Telefone {

private String nome;
private String telefone;

public String getNome() { 
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

}
```

E queria passar uma instância dessa classe por meio do bundle assim:

```
Telefone telefone = new Telefone();
telefone.setNome("nome");
telefone.setTelefone("12345");
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.put("telefone", telefone); //como passa esse objeto para o Bundle?
intent.putExtras(b);
```

Eu sei que o `Bundle` pode passar `String`, `int`, `float` que são tipos primitivos, mas como passar um objeto do tipo `Telefone`, como no exemplo acima descrito?

Comment: Como o @ramaral disse, poderia ser implementado o Serializable mas com problemas de performance. 
Deixo aqui uma referência que me ajudou quando estava no dilema entre usar Parcelable e Serializable. [Blog Developer Phil](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que um *Bundle* possa passar tipos não primitivos eles devem implementar a interface [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) ou [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

A implementação da *Serializable* é mais simples mas, no android, 
pode criar problemas de performance.

A implementação da *Parcelable* pode à primeira vista parecer complicada, mas apenas é trabalhosa<sup>(1)</sup>.

Exemplo da implementação:

```
public class DeviceEntity implements Parcelable{

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String codigo;
    private String number;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public DeviceEntity(long id, String name, String codigo, String number, boolean isSelected){

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.number = number;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    //Parcelable implementation

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        // Necessitamos de escrever cada um dos campos no parcel.
        // Quando formos ler do parcel estes são retornados pela mesma ordem
        dest.writeLong(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(codigo);
        dest.writeString(number);
        dest.writeByte((byte)(isSelected ? 1 : 0));

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<DeviceEntity> CREATOR = new
            Parcelable.Creator<DeviceEntity>() {

                @Override
                public DeviceEntity createFromParcel(Parcel source) {

                    return new DeviceEntity(source);
                }

                @Override
                public DeviceEntity[] newArray(int size) {

                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    //return new DeviceEntity[size];
                }
            }
    ;

    //Construtor usado pelo android para criar a nossa classe, neste caso DeviceEntity
    public DeviceEntity(Parcel source) {

        //Os valores são retornados na ordem em que foram escritos em writeToParcel
        id = source.readLong();
        name = source.readString();
        codigo = source.readString();
        number = source.readString();
        isSelected = source.readByte() != 0;
    }

    //Getters

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }
}
```

Para passar usar:

```
intent.putExtra("DeviceEntity", DeviceEntity);
```

Para receber:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
DeviceEntity deviceEntity = b.getParcelable("DeviceEntity");
```

<sub>(1) - Se estiver a usar o Android Studio há possibilidade de ele fazer o trabalho por si.

Após incluir `implements Parcelable`, na declaração da classe, coloque o cursor sobre ela e use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>. No menu que abre escolha **Add Parcelable Implementation**.</sub>

Comment: Se por acaso na minha classe eu tiver um objeto tipo BluetoothDevice device; posso usar o para escrever dest.writeValue(device); e device = (BluetoothDevice) source.readValue(null); para ler o valor, haverá algum problema?

Comment: +1 na sua resposta muito boa^^

Comment: @PedroRangel, você pode usar o `writeParcelable` e `readParcel` no `BluetoothDevice`, já que ele também herda de `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode passar diretamente no `Intent`, fazendo assim você precisa acrescentar uma implementação à sua classe `Telefone`:

```
public class Telefone implements Serializable
```

E então:

```
intent.putExtra("telefone", telefone);
```

Na `Activity` vai receber assim:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
telefone = (Telefone)intent.getSerializableExtra("telefone");
```

Comment: +1 na sua resposta brigado mesmo^^