# Envio de dados entre Activity de View e de Edição

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de agendamento de serviços e em uma ListView consigo pegar os dados de um cliente e passar para uma Activity de Consulta. Criei um menu de edição e gostaria de passar estes mesmos dados para a nova activity, porém eu somente consigo abrir a Activity sem passar os dados deste cliente.

Podem me ajudar?

Segue anexo o código.
Nesta activity ele seleciona um item da lista e joga o objeto cliente para uma segunda activity, que serve somente para consultar os dados:

```
public class AgendadoDiaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listadeAtendimentos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agendado_dia);

    listadeAtendimentos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_atendimentos);

    listadeAtendimentos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lista, View item, int position, long id) {
            Clientes cliente = (Clientes) listadeAtendimentos.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent pesquisa = new Intent(AgendadoDiaActivity.this, ViewCadastroAtendimentosActivity.class);
            pesquisa.putExtra("cliente", cliente);
            startActivity(pesquisa);
        }
    });
```

No onCreate desta Activity ele pega o objeto que mandei no extra e popula através do método preencheformulario() os itens na lista.

public class ViewCadastroAtendimentosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private HelperViewCadastroAtendimentos helper;
private HelperCadastroAtendimentos helperCadastro;
private Clientes cliente;
private Intent pesquisa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_cadastro_atendimentos);

    helper = new HelperViewCadastroAtendimentos(this);

    pesquisa = getIntent();
    cliente = (Clientes) pesquisa.getSerializableExtra("cliente");
    if(cliente != null){
        helper.preencheFormulario(cliente);
    }
}
```

Nesta activity tem um botão de editar, que chama outra activity de edição. É nela que não consigo pegar estes mesmos dados e jogar os valores do bd.

Comment: Para poder usar `putExtra()` com a classe *Clientes* ela deve implementar a interace Serializable ou preferencialmente a interface Parcelable, veja nesta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38471/2541) como implementá-la.

Answer (score 3):

Para complementar a resposta do @Leonardo Dias a utilização do código passando o extra pela intent e mais aconselhado fazer para dados primitivos, como int, byte, short, double e long e String que é um objeto mas nesse caso especifico e tratado como tipo primitivo. Quando for necessário enviar um objeto é mais aconselhado utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("value", SeuObjeto);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

....

Lembrando que o seu objeto deve implementar Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Raul, mostre seu código, é melhor para podermos ajudar.

Segue um exemplo de como passar dados entre Activitys:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserSignupActivity1.class);
intent.putExtra("user_name", nomeUser);
intent.putExtra("user_mail", emailUser);
intent.putExtra("facebookId", userId);
startActivity(intent);
```

E segue um exemplo de como receber na segunda Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){
     Intent in = getIntent();
     String nomeUserFacebook = in.getStringExtra("user_name");
     String emailUserFacebook = in.getStringExtra("user_mail");
     String idUserFacebook = in.getStringExtra("facebookId");
}
```

Comment: Porque verificar se 'extras != null' se por exemplo sempre o parâmetro vai ser passado?

Comment: Pode ser que de alguma falha na hora de passar os dados, ou algum dado não pegou, somente por garantia mesmo, pra evitar que o app de crash, mas não é obrigatório

Comment: Entendi........

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta e postei o código...obrigado!