# Passar lista para outra Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou criando um aplicativo, nesse momento do aplicativo, você escolhe quantos produtos vai pegar de uma Lista feita com RecyclerView e essa lista vai ser passada para outra Activity onde vai ser carregada em uma ListView.

Queria saber o que posso usar para armazenar os produtos clicados pelo usuário.
Estava pensando em usar sharedPreference, só que cada produto tem várias informações, como descrição, id, valor... e se for mais de um produto, como consigo pegar essas informações separadas? Uso HashMap? List?

Comment: Use SQLite.....

Comment: Estou usando o Firebase para armazenar, acha que é a melhor forma usar SQLite?

Comment: Se você irá salvar vários produtos, o sqlite seria mais viável, mas se vai armazenar apenas 1 produto, pode ser o sharedpreference mesmo.

Comment: Mas é que assim, os produtos já estão sendo armazenados no Firebase, queria uma forma funcionasse tanto pra um produto quanto pra mais, sem usar o SQLite, será que tem algum jeito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se apenas quer passar os itens seleccionados para outra Activity, guarde-os em um `ArrayList<Produto>`.

Coloque esse array no Intent com `intent.putExtra()`.

A classe *Produto* tem de implementar a interface Serializable ou Parcelable.
Veja como em [Como usar um Bundle com um tipo não primitivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38462/como-usar-um-bundle-com-um-tipo-n%c3%a3o-primitivo/38471#38471)